# Get nearby city values (HTML5 Geolocation and Google Maps API)

Tags: html, api, google-maps, geolocation

Ok, so I'm setting up a website where visitors can browse tournaments by selecting a city and state from a drop-down.

I want the browser to detect the visitor's city and state and place that as the default value in the drop-down when the site is first visited, hence displaying tournaments in that city initially. I am currently doing that by getting the coordinates with HTML5's Geolocation API and then converting it to a city and state with the Google Maps API.

Here's the issue, if the city the visitor is in is not listed in the dropdown, I would like for it to find the nearest city (from the visitor's city) and use that as the default value initially.

I see this done in many apps and websites nowadays, so can I do it with the current tools that I'm using (HTML5/Google API) or am I going to have to switch to some other technology?

Current JS, ignore the "alert(..."

```
// Get the visitors location byt latitude and longitude, and then by city and state.
function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
}
else {
    alert("Geolocation is not supported for this browser.")
}
}
function showPosition(position) {
var visitorLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': visitorLocation },
    function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
                var city, state;
                for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
                    var addr = results[0].address_components[i];
                    if (addr.types[0] == ['administrative_area_level_1'])
                        // State
                        state = addr.short_name;
                    else if (addr.types[0] == ['locality'])
                        // City
                        city = addr.long_name;
                }
                alert(city + ", " + state);
            }
        }
    }
);
}
getLocation();
```